# Azure SQL DB - Export data from a DB and insert into another DB?

Tags: import, export

I use Azure SQL DB (Single DB, Basic, DTU, Provisioned).

There are two different DBs, say, `DB-1` and `DB-2`.

For `DB-1`, I have Admin access.

For `DB-2`, I have read-only access. (No access to create new table.)

The two DBs have no links. I access them using SSMS.

The requirement:

1. In `DB-2`, there is a table `[EMP]` with 1000 rows.
2. Only 250 of them to be exported and inserted into a new table in `DB-1` (with all columns).

How can I achieve in SSMS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in only SSMS. If this is an ad-hoc project, I would query the records, copy and paste them into Excel, configure them in Excel for an insert statement, then paste them into an insert statement against DB-1.

If this is something that will need to be sustainable, I'd recommend looking into Azure Data Factory.